# Which languages have no repls

Tags: read-eval-print-loop

It seems these days most languages have some sort of read-eval-print loops, [cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) is one for c and c++, it makes me wonder what launguages don't (Java doesn't yet right)?

Comment: Most assembler languages wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Brainf**k](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/wiki/Brainfuck)

EDIT: Wait, someone actually did one in Scheme: http://github.com/buntine/Lisp-Brainfuck-REPL/